# Create an ERD diagram from a set of SQL CREATE TABLE statements

Tags: erd, snowflake

We have a Snowflake database that does not maintain relationships between tables. The lack of relationships is not my decision and I have no control over this. I would like to generate an ERD diagram showing how a number of tables are related to each other.

I do have the set of CREATE TABLE statements for the database, which includes the relationship information.

Is there a Windows software package or online tool that can take these CREATE statements and generate and ERD?

Answer (score 0):

You can import SQL statements to draw.io. See link.

[enter link description here](https://drawio-app.com/entity-relationship-diagrams-with-draw-io/#:%7E:text=Create%20an%20entity%20relationship%20diagram,from%20the%20General%20shape%20library)